# C++ application console not exiting

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.5 and Visual Studio 2012 to write a program in C++. In its simplest form I'm retrieving an image from a webcam, showing it on screen and then exit the application. The first parts work, but I cannot exit the application.

I'm using the `system("pause")` command instead of `cin.get()` at the end of my `main` function because I need that line of output right now, despite temporarily losing portability. And why? Because I'm seeing the "Press any key to continue..." line, but the console is not exiting.

I've tried 'pumping' using `waitKey(1)` just after `showFrame()`, but it doesn't help. If I remove `cvStartWindowThread()` nothing changes (that I notice, at least). The application seems unable to shut down the console. Visual Studio is still in debug mode, too, and I can't even break the program using Ctrl+C after returning from `showFrame()`. I have no idea how to solve this.

The project is still very much WIP, but I'll include the relevant code here:

Defines:

```
#define EXTERNAL_CAM    0
#define BUILT_IN_CAM    1
#define SINGLE_SHOT     0
#define VIDEO_GRAB      1
#define WINDOW      "Frame"
```

`main` function:

```
int main() {
    Mat frame = getFrameFromCam(EXTERNAL_CAM, SINGLE_SHOT);
    showFrame(WINDOW, frame);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`getFrameFromCam` function:

```
Mat getFrameFromCam(int cam, int captureMode) {
    Mat frame;
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(cam);
    IplImage* iplImage;
    switch(captureMode) {
    case SINGLE_SHOT:
        iplImage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        frame = iplImage;
        break;
    case VIDEO_GRAB:
        bool firstFrame = true;
        do {
            iplImage = cvQueryFrame(capture);
            frame = iplImage;
            showVideo(WINDOW, frame, firstFrame, false);
            firstFrame = false;
        } while (cin.get() != 'y');
        showVideo(WINDOW, frame, firstFrame, true);
        break;
    }

    return frame;
}
```

`showFrame` function:

```
void showFrame(string window, Mat frame) {
    cvStartWindowThread();
    namedWindow(WINDOW, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(WINDOW, frame);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow(WINDOW);

    return ; 
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `system("pause")` with something like `cin.get()` or `cv::waitKey()`? Does the app still not exit. Also, you're mixing the C and C++ APIs. Don't do this--just stick to C++.

Comment: No change. I've tried that already - thought I mentioned that. As I mentioned it is still WIP, but C API is those with cv-prefix right?

Comment: Also, please post the declarations of everything your posted code uses. I can guess the values of `WINDOW`, `SINGLE_SHOT`, etc, but it's polite and [helpful](http://sscce.org) to not make people trying to help work harder than they have to.

Comment: Come to think about it, you're warning me about the use of IplImage in cvQueryFrame? That is the function I found for getting frames from a webcam, if there is another function that does the same please enlighten me.

Comment: @Aurelius of course, I've added it - didn't even thought about adding those, sorry..

Comment: [`cv::VideopCapture`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture) is the C++ way to do it. If you're new to OpenCV, the main page has a "Tutorials" link. They're very helpful. Also, what happens if you press a key *twice* to try to exit the application?

Comment: No matter how many keys I press, the console stays open. I'll trying using `cv::VideoCapture`, thanks.

Comment: Can you remove the `destroyWindow` call in `showFrame`? I believe the windows get destroyed automatically so there's no need to do it manually. I think I may have encountered a bug in that function once. Hence posting as a comment instead of an answer

Comment: @maditya I've removed it in my own code, it doesn't change anything, but I'll leave it out. Just in case it's bugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering my own question, since nobody else have tried:

The problem is that I'm trying to get a frame from the camera using a seperate function. @Aurelius answered the question of sorts, by refering to `VideoCapture`. By using that function I'm able to cut down the necessary code in the `main` function - originally I tried to reduce the code in the `main` function by seperating the framegrabber from the `main`.

Someone more skilled in C++ and OpenCV than myself might be able to give a more correct answer, but here is my solution:

```
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"

#include <iostream>

#define EXTERNAL_CAM     0
#define BUILT_IN_CAM     1
#define WINDOW_TITLE     "Frame"

int main() {
    VideoCapture cap(EXTERNAL_CAM);
    Mat frame;
    if(!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "No cap.\n";
    } else {
        cap >> frame;
    showFrame(WINDOW_TITLE, frame);
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void showFrame(string window, Mat frame) {
    if(frame.data != NULL) {
        namedWindow(WINDOW_TITLE, 1);
        imshow(WINDOW_TITLE, frame);
        waitKey(30);
    } else {
        cout << "No frame detected!\n";
    }
    return ; 
}
```

Comment: I was having a similar issue, but after adding cvRealeaseCapture(&cap) to release the video capture when done it would terminate without any issues.